# Fonts resizing after clicking URL and clicking back button (C#, Bootstrap)

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of standard href links and click any to view a page.  After clicking the back button, the page fonts resize to about 10% of the original.  The fonts go back to normal after page refresh.

I compared the generated code before and after and there is no difference.  Cookies and cache cleared before testing even though the caching is disabled.

Comment: is there anything extra in your url after you press the back button?

Comment: No.  And the problem is, we're working on code that was developed by someone that recently left.  Very "unique" development standards which has turned out to be a real problem for everyone trying to support it.

Comment: Well we need either your code or a copy of the link, it is really hard to say without looking at it.

Comment: `Html.ActionLink("<#= RefNumber #>", "GetRequest", "Request", new { refNumber = "<#= RefNumber #>", subjectNumber = "<#= SortOrder #>" },
new { @class = "navButton" }).ToHtmlString() : "<#= RefNumber #>"))`